# Compare rows and calculate values according to trigger and clause with SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on SQL Server 2014.
I have a query which returns a list of Job orders that will consume Components (with a required quantity ReQ) and at a specific date (Req Dt).
I join this list to a stock table that provides for each component, the current available stock and the total of already reserved quantity.
The job order required quantity is not yet reserved/confirmed, thus not taken into account in the stock table.
The list is ordered by component number and date of need.

For each line **consuming** the **same** component, I want to add a column that calculates the projected Net Stock (NSt, remaining component quantity) and thus identify future missing components (when the projected Net Stock is 0 or below).

Looping into the list and for each component, the calculation rules would be :

1. For the first line (first component occurence): Net Stock = (Available stock - Reserved quantity - required quantity) from the current line.
2. For the second line (second component occurence): Net Stock = Net Stock from line 1 - required quantity of line 2
3. For the last line: Net Stock N = Net Stock N-1 - required quantity line N

If I use Excel it would look like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rN5j.jpg)

Many thanks in advance for help on this topic.

Thanks for your interest Marc and Larnu.

I have already created the SQL code that fetches the primary data; I need to modify the query in order to add 2 columns:

- Calculation of projected Net stock (NST).
- Attribute yes/no for low remaining stock (LSt) but this one I can handle.

The table structure is mainly based on the following columns:

- Job_No=Job order that consumes the needed quantity (ReQ)
- Cmp=Component code
- Req Dt=Need Date
- ReQ=Qty needed (quantity of component needed)
- AvSt=Available Stock from stock table
- ResQ=Total reserved Qty from stock table
- NSt=Net Stock (projected remaining stock)
- LSt="If Net Stock  >=0 then  No, If Net Stock <0 then Yes".

Available stock and Total reserved Qty are the current values from the stock table at the moment the query is run.

For each component, the first occurrence provides the initial Net Stock which is then used to calculate the Net Stock of the next occurrence (line).

When a new component is found, the same calculation process is restarted.

The difficult points for me are :

- How to use the calculated Net Stock value from the previous line into the current line.
- How to restart the calculation process each time a new component is found into the list.

Here are a set of data with expected results for NSt and LSt:

| Job_No | Comp | Req dt | ReQ | AvSt | ResQ | NSt | LSt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 273908 | F000307 | 03/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 572 | No |
| 273905 | F000307 | 03/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 571 | No |
| 273910 | F000307 | 03/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 570 | No |
| 273909 | F000307 | 03/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 569 | No |
| 273874 | F000307 | 03/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 568 | No |
| 273875 | F000307 | 03/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 567 | No |
| 273876 | F000307 | 03/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 566 | No |
| 273881 | F000307 | 03/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 565 | No |
| 273882 | F000307 | 03/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 564 | No |
| 273884 | F000307 | 10/11/2021 | 1 | 1675 | 1102 | 563 | No |
| 274135 | F000313 | 07/09/2021 | 4 | 41688 | 6 | 41678 | No |
| 274136 | F000313 | 20/09/2021 | 2 | 41688 | 6 | 41676 | No |
| 274202 | F000314 | 14/09/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | 20 | No |
| 274203 | F000314 | 14/09/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | 10 | No |
| 274205 | F000314 | 24/09/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | 0 | No |
| 274207 | F000314 | 27/09/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | -10 | Yes |
| 274210 | F000314 | 27/09/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | -20 | Yes |
| 274211 | F000314 | 12/10/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | -30 | Yes |
| 274212 | F000314 | 21/10/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | -40 | Yes |
| 274215 | F000314 | 21/10/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | -50 | Yes |
| 274220 | F000314 | 25/10/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | -60 | Yes |
| 274222 | F000314 | 25/10/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | -70 | Yes |
| 274230 | F000314 | 25/10/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | -80 | Yes |
| 274231 | F000314 | 26/10/2021 | 10 | 188 | 158 | -90 | Yes |

--My initial SQL:

```
SELECT 
    --A.[SCHN - Schedule number] 'Schedule'
    A.[MFNO - Manufacturing order number] 'Job_No',
    A.[MTNO - Component number] 'Comp',
    A.[RDAT - Reservation date] 'Req dt',
    A.[REQT - Reserved quantity] 'ReQ',
    C.[STQT - On-hand balance approved] 'AvSt', -- from stock table
    C.[REQT - Reserved quantity] 'ResQ',          -- from stock table
    /** This is the first projected Net Stock for the first component occurrence
        but how to calculate the next occurrence line with the previous line result? **/
    C.[STQT - On-hand balance approved]-C.[REQT - Reserved quantity]-A.[REQT - Reserved quantity] AS 'NSt',
    CASE 
        WHEN (C.[STQT - On-hand balance approved]-C.[REQT - Reserved quantity]-A.[REQT - Reserved quantity]) <= 0 
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No' 
    END AS 'LSt',
    /* (C.[STQT - On-hand balance approved]-C.[REQT - Reserved quantity]-A.[REQT - Reserved quantity])
        will be replaced by the new projected Net Stock when available*/
    A.[RGDT - Entry date]
FROM 
    [JOB ORDERS] A    
LEFT JOIN 
    [WAREHOUSE STOCK] C ON A.[MTNO - Component number] = C.[ITNO - Item number] 
                        AND A.[WHLO - Warehouse] = C.[WHLO - Warehouse]
WHERE
    A.[WMST - Material status] <= '44' 
    AND A.[SCHN - Schedule number] <> 0
    AND A.[RGDT - Entry date] > 20210101
    AND A.[REQT - Reserved quantity] > 0
ORDER BY 
    A.[MTNO - Component number], A.[RDAT - Reservation date]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?. You should also provide your table structure and sample data, with their desired result. You need to provide that information in text, not an image, so we can work with it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: What is your question here? You've listed off a bunch of requirements, but not told us what you're asking.

Comment: Please supply your existing query, as your requirements are completely unclear

Comment: I just reformulated my request and added my initial query. Hope it's clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use `SUM` as a window function.**

- Note the use of `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, this is necessary if the `ORDER BY` is non-deterministic, and is in any case more efficient
- Use meaningful table aliases, `A` `B` `C` [doesn't really help comprehension](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)
- Good whitespace formatting is essential
- Quote column names with `[]` not `''`
- I strongly recommend you name your columns something shorter that does not require quoting in the first place
- Date constants should be in quotes

```
SELECT
   --jo.[SCHN - Schedule number] [Schedule]
     jo.[MFNO - Manufacturing order number] [Job_No]
    ,jo.[MTNO - Component number] [Comp]
    ,jo.[RDAT - Reservation date] [Req dt]
    ,jo.[REQT - Reserved quantity] [ReQ]
    ,ws.[STQT - On-hand balance approved] [AvSt] -- from stock table
    ,ws.[REQT - Reserved quantity] [ResQ]          -- from stock table
      
    ,SUM(ws.[STQT - On-hand balance approved] - ws.[REQT - Reserved quantity] - jo.[REQT - Reserved quantity])
     OVER (PARTITION BY jo.[MTNO - Component number], jo.[WHLO - Warehouse]
           ORDER BY jo.[RDAT - Reservation date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
     ) as [NSt]

    ,case when (ws.[STQT - On-hand balance approved] - ws.[REQT - Reserved quantity] - jo.[REQT - Reserved quantity]) <= 0
         then 'Yes'
         else 'No' end as [LSt]

    ,jo.[RGDT - Entry date]

FROM [JOB ORDERS] jo
left join [WAREHOUSE STOCK] ws
    ON jo.[MTNO - Component number] = ws.[ITNO - Item number]
   and jo.[WHLO - Warehouse]  =ws.[WHLO - Warehouse]

where jo.[WMST - Material status] <= '44' 
  and jo.[SCHN - Schedule number] <> 0
  and jo.[RGDT - Entry date] > '20210101'
  and jo.[REQT - Reserved quantity] > 0
order by
  jo.[MTNO - Component number],
  jo.[RDAT - Reservation date];
```

Comment: Thanks Charlieface; I am using your proposed solution nearly as it is. I change for the rolling sum on quantity needed and then substract available stock and reserved qunantity; and I get my projected stock!